# What are the effects on the converter circuit due to lower vs higher switching frequency?

Tags: frequency, converter

I know that lower frequency and higher frequency are selected based on the application. But I read that higher frequency will usually have more EMI harmonic distortions. It would be nice if anyone explained the reason why.

At the same time, when there is lower switching frequency, I imagined that the di/dt of current in the inductor (particularly flyback transformer), will be higher, could anyone tell me what are the effects, both of higher frequency and the lower frequency switching in a DC-DC converter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Higher frequency** means faster switching and usually faster edges, meaning more and higher frequency harmonic content, which means higher EMI. Higher frequencies propagate easier, making mitigation harder.

However it also typically means smaller magnetic components (not as many volt-seconds for each switching period). However, AC losses (skin effect, proximity effect eddy and core losses) can be higher.

Lower inductor ripple currents may mean smaller output voltage ripple and lower output capacitance requirements.

Higher frequency switching also results in higher switching losses, as per-cycle losses happen more often. (Cap charging/discharging losses, FET crossover losses.)

So higher frequency often leads to smaller solution size but lower efficiency and higher EMI.

Higher switching frequency also raises one constraint on your control loop bandwidth, possibly enabling better transient response.

The converse is true for the **lower frequency** case.

These are generalizations, because much is topology and implementation dependent, so it's important to make the tradeoffs for your specific requirements.

A good rule of thumb is to use the lowest switching frequency you can get away with while meeting all of the other system requirements.

Comment: Can you explain how and why the AC losses in a converter/switch at higher switching frequency can be higher?

Comment: @Fredrick see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect and
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_effect_(electromagnetism) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_core